# Converting a list of strings into floats/ints in F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

Is there a quick and simple way to convert an entire list of strings into floats or integers
and add them together similar to this in F#?

```cs
foreach(string s in list)
{
    sum += int.Parse(s);
}
```

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you could make it look very similar in C# using LINQ: `var sum = list.Select(int.Parse).Sum()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this should have the same effect:

```
let sum = list |> Seq.map System.Int32.Parse |> Seq.sum
```

F# doesn't seem to support referring to the method on `int` so I had to use `System.Int32` instead.

In F# the type `seq` is an alias for the .NET `IEnumerable`, so this code works on arrays, lists etc.

Note the use of `Parse` in "point-free" style - a function without its argument can be used directly as an argument to another function that expects that type. In this case `Seq.map` has this type:

```
('a -> 'b) -> seq<'a> -> seq<'b>
```

And since `System.Int32.Parse` has type `string -> int`, `Seq.map System.Int32.Parse` has type `seq<string> -> seq<int>`.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to aim for minimal number of characters, then you can simplify the solution posted by Ganesh to something like this:

```
let sum = list |> Seq.sumBy int
```

This does pretty much the same thing - the `int` function is a generic conversion that converts anything to an integer (and it works on strings too). The `sumBy` function is a combination of `map` and `sum` that first projects all elements to a numeric value and then sums the results.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there are at least 3 different approaches:

1) The Seq.sum or sumBy approach described in the other answers is the canonical way of getting the sum in F#:

```
let sum = Seq.sumBy int list
```

2) For instructional purposes, it may be interesting to see how closely one can simulate C# behavior in F#; for instance, using a reference cell type:

```
let inline (+=) x y = x := !x + y
let sum = ref 0
for s in list do sum += int s
```

3) Same idea as 2), but using a byref pointer type:

```
let inline (+=) (x:_ byref) y = x <- x + y
let mutable sum = 0
for s in list do &sum += int s
```