# Is there a function in F# for parsing a string to an int?

Tags: string, casting, f#

It seems like there's a function for this in practically every language but I can't find one in [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/strings) or [Core.String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.string-module-%5Bfsharp%5D), and all the related questions on this site seem to ask for a function that goes from int to string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a list of strings into floats/ints in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825237/converting-a-list-of-strings-into-floats-ints-in-f)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straight up parsing - the F# standard function `int`:

```
let fortyTwo = int "42"
```

However, this function may throw an exception if the input is not a decimal number. For exception-less parsing use the .NET function `System.Int32.TryParse`.